# jQuery UI dialog: Combine width:auto and minWidth

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am initializing my jQuery dialog like this:

```
.dialog({
    maxHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 500,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto"
});
```

The goal is to have the dialog auto-size width to content on open, but cap the max width to 500.  When it opens, it's honoring `width: "auto"`, but not `minWidth: 500` (it opens very narrow for smaller content, but I want it to be at least 500 wide).   I think there's either 1) a bug in the dialog or 2) I can't set both during initialization.  I consider there to be a bug because, when I click the border to resize it, it automatically snaps to the `minWidth` at the slightest drag of the border.  This tells me it recognizes the `minWidth` property, but doesn't initialize it.  However, when I omit `width: "auto"`, it initializes at `minWidth` as expected.

Here's a fiddle showing the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/oedgwkvL/1/

Dialog initializes at the size of the content, but I want `minWidth` to take priority.  Drage one of the border as little as a pixel and it will snap to `minWidth` size.